# Installing Umbraco package breaks site

Tags: content-management-system, umbraco, umbraco7

I have an Umbraco site that was working fine and I could login to the Umbraco back office

I installed the Links Picker package - https://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/links-picker/ -  and then was not able to login to the backoffice OR my website. I was greeted with the message

> Type
>   'Umbraco.Core.PropertyEditors.ValueConverters.IntegerValueConverter'
>   cannot be an IPropertyValueConverter for property
>   'mainBrandLogoHeight' of content type 'Brand' because type
>   'Umbraco.Core.PropertyEditors.ValueConverters.IntegerValueConverter'
>   has already been detected as a converter for that property, and only
>   one converter can exist for a property.

I have been into the installedpackages.config file and removed the  entry for this package but my site/back office still will nto load

How can I login or resolve this issue?

Comment: Have you removed the `our.umbraco.linkspicker.dll` file from your bin folder?

Comment: Thanks Rob, that worked. Could you make it an answer so I can tick it for you?

Comment: Thanks @Mike, just posted an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package's `our.umbraco.linkspicker.dll` file is still in the /bin folder of your project and so Umbraco is still trying to use it.

When manually uninstalling a package it's important to remove any associated files listed in the `installedPackages.config` file.